# How to use vue-gapi plugin with router.js and router guards

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, google-api-js-client

I use a vue-gapi https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-gapi in my code to access Google Calendar API. I was successful to install and use this plugin to get data from Calendar API. I now struggle to use router guards.

plugins/vuagapi.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueGapi from 'vue-gapi';

const apiConfig = {
  apiKey: '***',
  clientId:
    '***.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  discoveryDocs: [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest',
  ],
  scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly',
  prompt: 'select_account',
};

Vue.use(VueGapi, apiConfig);
```

router/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Home from '../views/Home.vue';
import Dashboard from '../views/Dashboard.vue';
import Login from '../views/Login.vue';
import '../plugins/vuegapi.js';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: '*',
    redirect: '/',
  },
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'Login',
    component: Login,
  },
  {
    path: '/dashboard',
    name: 'Dashboard',
    component: Dashboard,
    meta: {
      authRequired: true,
    },
  },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes,
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.authRequired)) {
    if (this.$gapi.currentUser()) {
      next();
    } else {
      alert('You must be logged in to see this page');
      next({
        path: '/login',
      });
    }
  } else {
    next();
  }
});

export default router;
```

I am getting: vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2314 TypeError: Cannot read property '$gapi' of undefined.

Anyone can point me to right direction? I am able to use this plugin in .vue files but not in another plain .js, suspecting that this $gapi exists only as Vue instakce property/method? As I am beginner I do not know how to import it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you wanna access Vue instance inside your router use `router.app` instead of `this`

change this line :

```
this.$gapi.currentUser()
```

to this:

```
router.app.$gapi.currentUser()
```

---

you can read more about Router Instance Properties in : https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-instance-properties

Comment: you're welcome, enjoy coding :)